# Como puedo refactorizar exceso de if con polimorfismo en php

Tags: php, polimorfismo, refactoring

Supongamos que tengo una clase de nombre User con un metodo post que recibe un parámetro y dependiendo del contenido ejecuta un método.

```
class User
{
    public static function  post($request)
    {
        if ($request[0] == 'register') {
            return self::register();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'login') {
            return self::login();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'change') {
            return self::changePaswd();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'reset') {
            return self::resetPaswd();
        // Dispara una excepción
        throw new Exception("No existe el metodo");
    }
}
```

En este momento son pocas opciones posibles pero puede crecer mucho mas por lo tanto creo que lo mejor es refactorizar con polimorfismo, gracias!

Comment: duda: ¿por qué crees que aquí es necesario el polimorfismo?

Comment: Que tal @Aprendiz, en primera si bien en el ejemplo son 4 diferentes opciones este método puede llegar a tener un número elevado de opciones, por otra parte no es un código que se vea muy limpio aunque resuelva el problema. y por ultimo como esto puede repetirse bastante puede caer en la complejidad ciclomatica que viola la regla de code size de mess. Sin embargo otras sugerencias para refactorizar y disminuir el numero de puntos de decision es bienvenida y se agradecerá infinitamente. :D

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que tú quieres es muy fácil con php ya que este permite que el nombre de los métodos se pueda llamar de forma dinámica.
Ejemplo:

```
<?php
class User
{
  /**
   * @param $method => Nombre del método que quiere llamar
   * @return mixed
   */
  public static function post($method)
  {
      return self::{$method}();
  }

  public static function register() {
      echo 'Método register';
  }

  public static function login() {
      echo 'Método login';
  }
}
User::post('login');
```

Con esto al llamar al método post simplemente le pasas como parámetro el nombre del método que quieres ejecutar y listo, te evitas de hacer muchos if, puede tener los métodos que quieras y solo necesitas el nombre para ejecutarlo.

Comment: Hola @Darwin Zamora, gracias por la pronta respuesta, funciona perfecto, voy a extender un poco mas mi necesidad: Estoy refactorizando mi código con la intención de tenerlo limpio y para ello utilizo el PHP Mess Detector y de la manera que acertadamente sugieres el mess enviaría los warnings de: **Avoid unused private methods such as register**, login, etc. Entonces si de plano no hay otra manera diferente de refactorizar las condicionales tendré que sacrificar la **complejidad cíclica** para evitar al **avoid unused methods**. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que request siempre va a tener el primer elemento como la acción que quieres realizar:

```
<?php 
class User
{
    public static function post($request)
    {
        $method = $request[0];
        if(!method_exists($this, $method){
            throw new Exception("No existe el metodo");            
        }
        return self::{$method}();
    }

    private static function register(){};
    private static function login(){};
    private static function change(){};
    private static function reset(){};
}
```

Comment: Hola @jordicea gracias por tu pronta respuesta, como le comentaba a Darwin Zamora, la solución que planteas funciona a la perfección sin embargo el PHP mess Detector me envía warnings de avoid unused methods y mi intención es mantener el código limpio, Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Revisa tu código y como implementas usas la clase que tiene esos métodos: (namespace, autoload...) quizá el problema en sí no es del código si no de cómo lo interpreta el mess detector vs cómo realmente está, es un problema a veces común con algunos IDE.

Comment: Hola @jordicea gracias por tu respuesta, no me quedo muy claro a que te refieres podrias poner un ejmplo por favor. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Por ejemplo, en lugar de llamarlos dinámicamente, puedes llamar de forma individual, con un switch por ejemplo:

    switch ($method) {
                case 'register':
                    self::register();
                    break;

               // Resto de métodos [...]

                default:
                    throw new Exception('No existe el método');
                    break;
    }

Comment: Gracias @jordicea, aprecio mucho tus aportaciones, te comento que de hecho así los llamo, a través de un switch, la llamada dinámica la hice en un intento de refactorizar en primera instancia el if-elseif y en segunda instancia el switch pero al hacerlo fue que recibe del PHPMD el mensaje de evitar métodos no utilizados. Mi afición por el código limpio me llevo a buscar en la internet y encontré sugerencias recomendando refactorizar con polimorfismo las sentencias switch pero nunca entendí como ya que no encontré ejemplos.